# Scala- read values from a map based on keys

Tags: scala

is there any better way to read values from a map based on keys if I have more keys in a map?

currently I have a **Map[String, List[String]]** which can have more than **20 keys**:

I am using below for retrieving values for each keys

```
val names= map.getOrElse("Name", List.empty)
.
.
.
val cities = map.getOrElse("City", List.Empty)
```

Please help If I can write this in better way.

Comment: Why do you want to populate 20+ individual variables (`names`, `cities`, etc.) if the data already exists in your `Map` and is readily accessible (e.g. `map.getOrElse(...)`)? What purpose is served by duplicating all the data?

Comment: I need to use it so many places and I dont want  to write always map.getOrElse(...) so storing in a variable . Please suggest, i am new to scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I very much doubt you're doing yourself any favors by replicating the `Map` data into local variables.

One thing you could do is employ pattern matching to save *some* (not much) typing.

```
val knownKeys = List("Name", "City", "Country") // etc. etc.

val List(names
        ,cities
        ,countries
        // etc. etc.
        ) = knownKeys.map(data.getOrElse(_, List()))
```

A major drawback to this idea is that the list of keys has to be in the exact same order as the order of variables in the extraction.

A better idea is to give your `Map` its own default.

```
val data = Map("City" -> List("NY","Rome")
              ,"Name" -> List("Ed","Al")
              // etc. etc.
              ).withDefaultValue(List.empty[String])
```

Then you don't need `.getOrElse()`.

```
data("City")     // res0: List[String] = List(NY, Rome)
data("Airport")  // res1: List[String] = List()
```